# Invoke part of mainform

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have an application with 8 threads. The main of the app is to display realtime information from 4 outputs and also write the information to a file.

Now, I do not know very much in the domain of multi-threading, but I have succeeded in creating the 4 threads,and if I do not log the info into the rich text boxes, they work ok, they write the info into the files.

My question is: Can I display real time info, from each output on the same form (MainForm)
Outputs work independent one to each other

[image]

Below is the code I use to log the info into the richtextbox:

```
 Public Sub LogInBoxOutput2(ByVal [RichTextBox] As RichTextBox, textColor As Color, ByVal [text] As String, Optional logToFile As Boolean = False)

    Dim textToWrite As String = "[" & Now.ToString("dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") & "] - " & [text]

    If logNodesValues Then
        Me.InvokeIfRequired(Sub()

                                If textColor = Nothing Then
                                    [RichTextBox].SelectionColor = Color.Black
                                Else
                                    [RichTextBox].SelectionColor = textColor
                                End If


                                [RichTextBox].SelectedText = textToWrite

                                If scrollToBottom Then
                                    [RichTextBox].Select([RichTextBox].Text.Length - 1, 0)
                                    [RichTextBox].ScrollToCaret()
                                End If
                                [RichTextBox].AppendText(vbCrLf)

                                If logToFile Then
                                    writeToFileQueue2.Enqueue(textToWrite & vbCrLf)
                                End If

                            End Sub)
    Else
        writeToFileQueue2.Enqueue(textToWrite & vbCrLf)
    End If
End Sub

  <Extension()>
Public Sub InvokeIfRequired(ByVal Control As Control, ByVal Method As Action)
    If Control.InvokeRequired Then
        Control.Invoke(Method)
    Else
        Method.Invoke()
    End If
End Sub
```

Do you have any ideas, what could I do? Is there something like in ASP.NET where you could refresh only a frame/part of the page (meaning to invoke only a part of the mainform)?

thank you

Comment: "invoke only a part of the mainform" is a meaningless concept. The issue is that you cannot call a method or get/set a property of a control on any thread other than the UI thread. All you're doing is executing a method on the UI thread in order to access the control, rather than on the current background thread. Once you're on the UI thread, you can do anything to any control, just as always.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're encountering?  You haven't shown us that `InvokeIfRequired` method but presumably it tests `InvokeRequired` and calls `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` if it's `True`. That's all that's required to execute code on the UI thread. What's the actual issue?

Comment: The problem is that somehow the threads synchronize themselves, because they invoke the main thread at very short time intervals... and so, the logged time is the same in all 4 richtextboxes. 
If I do not display anything in the richtexboxes, and only write information to the files, than everything is alright

Comment: I expect the issue is that your lambda is using the current of the `textToWrite` variable when it executes rather than the value when it was called. Try passing that value as an argument rather than using it within the lamba.  You may have to modify your `InvokeIfRequired` method in order to do that.

Comment: Updating the UI is an expensive operation. You could change your `InvokeIfRequired()` method to call `Control.BeginInvoke()` instead so that it doesn't block the threads.

Comment: Though the best and least expensive way to update the UI would be to queue the text to be written to each RTB as well, then use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to empty each queue into the RTBs.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I tried to modify the extension, to use BeginINvoke, but I have no ideas of how to add beginInvoke to the Action. 
I would prefer this method, to use BEginInvoke, instaed of doing a concurentqueue which needs to be emptied at some time

Comment: The problem is that if you update it a lot your UI might start running slowly or even freeze. Creating four queues (or just one) and using a `Timer` gives both the UI and your processor some rest. You could create your own `Structure` or `Class` to add to the queue that holds information about what text to output, in which color and to which RTB (the last only if you use one queue). Set the timer's `Interval` to 1 and it will run as often as possible (approximately every 50 ms). The UI will update very frequently but still won't take too much time of your processor.

Comment: Great!. Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it!
Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't use `Action.BeginInvoke()` by the way because it executes on a thread-pool thread, so you still can't access the UI. If the `Else` statement is executed that means you are already on the UI thread, in which case the call needs to be blocking. So you should keep that line `Method.Invoke()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of invoking you should queue all the messages to be outputted to the UI as well in order to give the UI and your processor some rest. Then use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with an `Interval` of 1 to empty that queue as often as possible (approximately every 50 ms) and write the messages into each `RichTextBox`.

You can define your own data type that holds the necessary information for each message:

```
Public Structure OutputMessage
    Public Color As Color?
    Public Text As String
    Public [RichTextBox] As RichTextBox
    Public ScrollToBottom As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Color As Color?, ByVal ScrollToBottom As Boolean, ByVal [RichTextBox] As RichTextBox)
        Me.Text = Text
        Me.Color = Color
        Me.ScrollToBottom = ScrollToBottom
        Me.RichTextBox = [RichTextBox]
    End Sub
End Structure
```

Then in your form:

```
Private MessageQueue As New ConcurrentQueue(Of OutputMessage)

Dim WithEvents UpdateTimer As New Timer With {.Interval = 1, .Enabled = True}

Private Sub UpdateTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateTimer.Tick
    Dim Message As OutputMessage
    While MessageQueue.TryDequeue(Message)
        PrintMessage(Message)
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub PrintMessage(ByVal Message As OutputMessage)
    If Not Message.Color.HasValue Then
        Message.RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black
    Else
        Message.RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Message.Color.Value
    End If

    Message.RichTextBox.SelectedText = Message.Text

    If Message.ScrollToBottom Then
        Message.RichTextBox.Select(Message.RichTextBox.Text.Length - 1, 0)
        Message.RichTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
    End If
    Message.RichTextBox.AppendText(vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

Finally, in your threads:

```
Public Sub LogInBoxOutput2(ByVal [RichTextBox] As RichTextBox, textColor As Color?, ByVal text As String, Optional logToFile As Boolean = False)

    Dim textToWrite As String = "[" & Now.ToString("dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") & "] - " & text

    If logNodeValues Then
        MessageQueue.Enqueue(New OutputMessage(textToWrite, textColor, scrollToBottom, [RichTextBox]))
    End If

    If logToFile Then
        writeToFileQueue2.Enqueue(textToWrite & vbCrLf)
    End If

End Sub
```